# How to get the row count from a table related to other table?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I am new to mysql and database concepts and I will try to explain my question through these two minimal tables, here is the scenario for which I need to write a query,

```
Table : Fruits
| FruitId | FruitName |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Mango          |
| 2        | Apple          | 
| 3        | Papaya        |

Table : FruitSubClasses
| FruitSubClassID | FruitSubClass   | FruitID|
| ---------- -----| --------------- |-----------|
| 100             | Alphonso        |1|
| 101             | Irwin           |1|
| 200             | Fuji            |2|
| 201             | Golden Delicious|2|
```

I want to get data of all such Fruits from Table 1 such that there are no rows for these fruits(no subclasses) in Table 2. From what I searched I think I will need to use Joins and Count but I don't know how to use them in this situation.

I can describe it like "For each FruitID in Fruits, Fetch the FruitID and FruitName from Fruits such that this FruitID is not present in FruitSubClasses" but could not make a working query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an `OUTER JOIN` to solve this one, particularly a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (also known as `LEFT JOIN`) like so:

```
SELECT F.FruitID, F.FruitName
FROM Fruits F
LEFT JOIN FruitSubClasses FSC
    ON F.FruitID = FSC.FruitID
WHERE FSC.FruitID IS NULL
```

A `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows from the table on the left-hand side of the `JOIN` clause regardless of the match in the predicate of the `ON` clause. For rows where there are no matches on the right-hand side, `NULL` values are returned for the columns of the right-hand table. Knowing this we can then filter out anything that matches in the `JOIN` with the `WHERE` clause above, and only get the non-matching `Fruits` (that don't exist in `FruitSubClasses`).

And if you wanted just the row counts in a single scalar value, you can use the same query above with the `COUNT(*)` function like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Fruits F
LEFT JOIN FruitSubClasses FSC
    ON F.FruitID = FSC.FruitID
WHERE FSC.FruitID IS NULL
```

Comment: I got an "Ambiguous Column Name" error but fixed it by modifying the query and adding as "Select F.FruitID, F.FruitName". Thanks for the info, it worked!

Comment: @Rohit Yes sorry, that happens when the same column name exists more than once in the dataset and you forget to use the alias to specify which entity you want it from. Updating my answer now. Thank you!

Comment: I got this query to work `Select FruitID, FruitName from Fruits where FruitID NOT IN (Select DISTINCT FruitID from FruitSubClasses)`, this does appear to be returning what I want but not sure if it is the right way to achieve it in general. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps a GROUP BY is needed?

Comment: @Rohit Yes that query you created also works too but generally can be less efficient than the `LEFT JOIN` query I provided.